configure an eclipselink non-JTA sequence connection pool without jndi or persistance.xml
I am trying to find way to set eclipselink sequence pool datasource programmatically and not using JNDI (spring application deployed on cloud foundry). i need to set datasource explicitly as creation of datasource needs certificate authentication to postgres (on GCP)etc.
can we set DataSource to property 'eclipselink.jdbc.sequence-connection-pool.non-jta-data-source' instead of jndi name?
   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setPersistenceUnitName("int_portal");
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factory.setJpaDialect(new EclipseLinkJpaDialect());

        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setLoadTimeWeaver(loadTimeWeaver);
        factory.setJtaDataSource(dataSource);

        // PersistenceUnitProperties.CONNECTION_POOL_SEQUENCE;
        Map<String, Object> propMap = factory.getJpaPropertyMap();

        propMap.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
        propMap.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.SESSION_CUSTOMIZER, IPSessionCustomizer.class.getName());
        *propMap.put("eclipselink.jdbc.sequence-connection-pool", "true");
        propMap.put("eclipselink.jdbc.sequence-connection-pool.non-jta-data-source", "java:/comp/env/jdbc/intDB");


